# how to change li list from veritcal orientation to horizontal orientation

Tags: html, css, list, adaptive-design

I have a page on which i'm worinking on an adaptive mobile design. Now, I have the main navighation figured out, but I have a second navigation that looks like:

```
<div id="secondnav">
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color:#000;padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;margin:0px;font-size:150%;font-weight:bold;color:#eee">Overview</li>
      <li><a href="?q=node/16"><span>Accommodations</span></a></li>
<li><a href="?q=node/84"><span>Fitness Classes</span></a></li>
<li><a href="?q=node/40"><span>Cultural Activities</span></a></li>
<li><a href="?q=node/7"><span>Our History</span></a></li>
<li><a href="?q=node/8"><span>We are Secwepemc</span></a></li>
<li><a href="?q=node/30"><span>Pictographs</span></a></li>
<li><a href="?q=node/9"><span>Getting Here</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

it is currently vertically displayed and I need it to change to horizontal orientation when my page's with is below `900px`. http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/content/lodge - just shrink it's width to see what I'mn talking about.

Thank you!

Comment: here's a pen for you to try out, demonstrating the inline and float media query-based answers. I used 400px as the break point http://codepen.io/henry/pen/gbRXRg?editors=110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's proposed below is the "mobile-first" approach. Basically, you first style the elements the way they would look on smallest screens, and then progressively adjust styles as screen width grows, as in below example.

For having elements be inline, you can use `display:inline-block,` but there can be undesired small spaces in-between, so I've used `display:block` combined with `float:left` - same effect, without those spaces.

```
#secondnav ul li {
    display:block;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    #secondnav ul li {
        float:left
    }

    #secondnav {
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

EDIT: In your particular example, the container, `#secondnav`, has a limitied width, so the above code won't work until you increase it's width too.

EDIT 2: Your menu items will still go to multiple lines, as their width is set to 301 I think. Try to set it to auto, or something less (like 100px). Also you'll need to apply a background color to the container (#secondnav I guess), but these are styling considerations out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

CSS
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```